# Grep colorize complete line

Tags: grep

I have a continuous output from a program which I grep for keywords. Now I want that the complete line is red colored, not just the keyword. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use RegEx that [find lines containing certain words](http://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html):

- Matches a complete line of text that contains any of the words "one", "two" or "three":

  - greedy: `^.*\b(one|two|three)\b.*$`
  - lazy: `^.*?\b(one|two|three)\b.*$`
- Matches a complete line of text that contains all of the words "one", "two" and "three":
  `^(?=.*?\bone\b)(?=.*?\btwo\b)(?=.*?\bthree\b).*$`